# Possible to request permissions at the same time?

Tags: ios

on my application we have some permissions that are absolutely required for the application to work, for these permissions we have interfaces set up explaining to the user why they're required, and then asking the user to grant the permission.

However, it seems a little redundant to ask for certain permissions, such as "Photos" and "Camera". Is it possible to (`in iOS 8+`) ask for both permissions simultaneously? I don't recall ever granting an application access to my photo library **AND** camera, but it seems like it's required from within my application.

Currently I am requesting the permissions back to back, however the multiple popup boxes is more annoying than anything, especially when it feels unnecessary.

Comment: good question. I will say no because apple has two permissions one to access the pictures in your camera roll and the other to access camera features themselves. Unless you can convince apple I think you may have to live with that. Oh yeah if your camera has movie feature then you will get a 3rd pop-up to grant mic access too ... how fun eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it seems like Camera and Photos should be lumped together as one permission, their both using two different frameworks (AVCaptureDevice and PHPhotoLibrary) so there are two separate authorization requirements, (even if you are using the UIImagePickerController).

I would offer that you try to take that opportunity to make it more of an experience for requesting authorization and explaining to your user why its necessary.

There are numerous articles ([here's one](https://library.launchkit.io/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions-96fa4eb54f2c#.c7ixtimdm)), and some designers at work, at least my work, who will rave about how you get a better acceptance rate when you take some time to explain to the user why access is needed.

Also the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LocationServices.html) has a page on Accessing User Data and how you should handle it

> Make sure users understand why they’re being asked to share their personal data. It’s natural for people to be suspicious of a request for their personal information if they don’t see an obvious need for it. To avoid making users uncomfortable, make sure the alert appears only when they attempt to use a feature that clearly needs to know their information. For example, people can use Maps when Location Services is off, but they see an alert when they access the feature that finds and tracks their current location.
>
> Describe why your app needs the information, if it’s not obvious. You
>   can provide text that appears in the alert, below a system-provided
>   title such as ““App Name” Would Like to Access Your Contacts” or for
>   location notifications, “Allow “App Name” to Use Your Location While
>   You Use the App?”. You want this text to be specific and polite so
>   that people understand why you’re asking for access to their
>   information and don’t feel pressured.